# Efficient way to calculate on all row-pairs of a large matrix?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I need to do some time-consuming calculations on all row-pairs of a large matrix M, like:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        time_comsuming_calculation(M[i,:],M[j:])
```

Since I am new to parallel computing , after studied the example in [Writing parallel computation results in shared memory](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html), I tried to do parallel computing with joblib  as below:

```
dump(M, M_name)
M=load(M_name,mmap_mode='r')
...
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(paracalc)(u,v,M)
                                for u,v in itertools.combinations(range(M.shape[0]),2))
```

However, it turned to be unbearably much slower than non-parallel version. Computing on each row-pair consumed even more seconds than `num_cores=1`.
I am wondering what's wrong with my parallel implementation. Is `mpi4py` a better choice? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, still no answers but I've managed to work it out.
The first interesting fact I found is when I commented out these two lines,

```
# dump(M, M_name)
# M=load(M_name,mmap_mode='r')
```

by which the memmap array were no longer used to take place of memory array, it went much faster. I don't know why up to now. Is there a memmap lock or something?

Then, I read this article [Parallel and HPC with Python (or numpy)](http://yjliu.net/blog/2014/04/25/parallel-in-python.html)  and decided to turn to `mpi4py`. After hours of struggling with debugging, I got satisfying results.